# Mongo DB - MissingSchemaError

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working with mongo DB and mongoose and I'm getting the following error when running the code below.

> "MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Project".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)"

```
import {...}

const { school } = request.params;

const document = await Document.find({
   }).populate('project').lean();

if (document.project.school != school)
                throw HTTP.forbidden('ERROR.DOCUMENT_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_YOUR_SCHOOL');
```

My schemas look as follows

```
const Document = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    type: { type: String },
    project: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const Project = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    school: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'School'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const School = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    curriculum: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Curriculum'
    }],
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to overcome this everything has been initialised by the time this section of code is getting called?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created model for each schema, try writing your `ref`s using `lowercase`:

```js
const Document = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    type: { type: String },
    project: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'project'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const Project = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    school: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'school'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const School = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    curriculum: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'curriculum'
    }],
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```